# Access-Control-Allow-Origin with instagram api

Tags: ajax, api, cors, instagram

I am trying to get my instagram feed with the following code

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/xxxxxxx/media/recent/?access_token=xxxxxxxxxxx',

      error: function() {
        alert('error');
      },

      success: function(data) {
       alert('yes');
      },
      type: 'GET'
   });
```

The error I am getting is

**No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**

Is there a work around?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instagram API supports `JSONP`, so add `&callback=?` to the url and add `dataType: "jsonp"` to the `$.ajax()` call, like below:

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/xxxxxxx/media/recent/?access_token=xxxxxxxxxxx&callback=?',

      error: function() {
        alert('error');
      },

      success: function(data) {
       alert('yes');
      },
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: "jsonp"
   });
```