# How to make api call to Instagram with axios without CORS error

Tags: reactjs, cors, frontend, instagram-api, axios

```
componentDidMount() {
let token = this.getAccessToken('access_token');

let config = {
  headers: {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Accept: 'application/json'
  }
}

if (token) {
  axios.get('https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/?access_token=' + token, config)
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res)
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
    })
}
```

Trying to make an call to Instagram's API but I keep getting this error:

[image]

I'm using React.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Instagram supports cross origin requests. They do support jsonp though.

[Access-Control-Allow-Origin with instagram api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41486160/access-control-allow-origin-with-instagram-api)

[instagram jquery ajax type="GET, can't get around CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31505596/instagram-jquery-ajax-type-get-cant-get-around-cors)

Comment: yeah I got it working with jQuery using jsonp but axios doesn't support jsonp

Comment: This is the correct answer to the question that was asked. If axios doesn’t support JSONP, that’s a different problem (and the solution is to not use axios if you want to work with the Instragram API from your frontend JavaScript code). And you don’t need jQuery to use JSONP — you just need to use standard JavaScript and the DOM to create a `script` element in the DOM and set its `src` attribute to the `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/?access_token=' + token` value .

Answer (score 0):

You can use a middleman to make your request server-side. There are several to choose from when I search 'no cors npm', but here is an example: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

Comment: Ideally you would configure your server to send this request, but this works if you don't want to get that technical, it's especially handy for testing.